# WinSCP: tunnel through SSH to SFTP: save files on the intermediate machine (instead of local machine)

Tags: ssh, sftp, tunnel, winscp

I use WinSCP from a local machine (machine A) to an SSH machine (machine B) which I use to tunnel through to machine C (to which I connect through SFTP). So far all good.

(create new session with the hostname and login/pass of machine C then do -> advanced settings -> connection: tunnel and put the hostname and login/pass of machine B in there.)

Now comes the rub.

I would like to copy files from machine C to machine B, *without an intermediate copy to machine A* (the files are too big and the connection between A and B too feeble).

I have of course tried opening both sessions (A<->B and B<->C) at once and copy-paste files from C to B but it seems an intermediate save on A is attempted: the box "Duplicate via local Temporary copy" in the "Duplicate" menu is checked in and I cannot uncheck it. The online help [mentions](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_duplicate)

> "When duplicating to different session, the only option is to
>   duplicate via local temporary copy"

My question is: Is there a way to transfer files from C to B without intermediate copy to B?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get files from C to B directly is running a software (SFTP/SCP client) on either of these machines. WinSCP cannot do that for you.

It might be possible with command-line [`scp`](https://man.openbsd.org/scp), which has server-to-server copy mode (it internally runs `scp` client on one of the servers over SSH connection). Though the tunneling part will complicate it. I didn't test it, but a setup like this may work:

```
scp C:file.txt localhost:file.txt -J B
```